# Timeout error when moving data using Copy Data Activity with Upsert in Azure Data Factory

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am facing a timeout issue.
Basically, I move data from source to target using copy data activity and the Table has 600k rows.

I use upsert instead of the insert because I want to check if the same data is present then the data does not move but I am facing a time issue.

Below is the error

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since UPSERT = INSERT + UPDATE , if I was you I could have investigated this by

1. Checking if INSERT works . Take one dummy row which does not exist on the DB and see if this work . If it does not then it means that neither UPDATE or INSERT works . I will try to SELECT IN a lookup to check if the any data is accessable from ADF.

2.If INSERT works but UPDATE fails , I will connect to the DB may be using may be SSMS and try to see if somethng like

SELECT * from yourTable where id = {someexistid}

If this timesout , you may have to create a INDEX ON the table ( may be )

3. There is a timeout setting on the copy activity and you can try to see if increasing that helps .